# PHP - Displaying Json encoded messages

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am building an ajax form with JQuery and PHP. The PHP file validates the submitted data and sends back json encoded messages. If however javascript is turned off, the messages look like the following:

```
{"error":true,"msg":"- Please enter your name!"}
```

What method is used to display just the message if javascript is not enabled in the browser?

This is the PHP function I currently use to send back messages to JQuery:

```
function mcResponseMessage($mcRespBool, $mcRespMessage){
   $mcReturn['error'] = $mcRespBool;
   $mcReturn['msg'] = '- '.$mcRespMessage;
   echo json_encode($mcReturn);
   exit();
```

}

Thank you!

Comment: In 2012 no one cares of users without javascript

Comment: you can add a parameter to the ajax url using javascript. so if the parameter is not present you serve a page rather than the json code

Comment: If the JavaScript is not enabled, then there will not be an AJAX request to submit data in the first place.

Comment: How are you sending an AJAX request without JavaScript?

Comment: If javascript is turned off, then the form just submits to php as normal. The messages are still sent back ajax encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a flag in your AJAX request stating that it is an AJAX request so you can output JSON for the AJAX request and output just the message when the form is submitted normally:

```
$.ajax({
    data : { ajax : true }
    ...the rest of your AJAX code here
});
```

Then in your PHP script:

```
if (isset($_GET['ajax']) && $_GET['ajax'] == true) {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'msg' => '- Please enter your name!'));
} else {
    echo '- Please enter your name!';
}
```

Note that if you are using a `post` type AJAX call then the PHP will need to change to reference that fact: `$_POST['ajax']` instead of `$_GET['ajax']`.

Comment: Thank you! You were the only one who understood my question and this is exactly the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely nothing you can do with a JSON response if Javascript is disabled. If you want to support users with scripting disabled then you have to orchestrate things in a better way:

1. Make your form POST to the server when submitted; the server should validate the input and redirect to either a "success" page or back to the same page if there was some error (i.e. use the [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)). Before redirecting, save any validation errors in session variables so that you can display them after redirecting. This is how non-JS-enabled clients will interact with your site; *the server will never return JSON in this mode*.
2. Add Javascript that prevents the form from being submitted, and fires off an AJAX request to the server to validate the data instead. In effect, you have now hijacked the process for script-enabled users. The server should run the same validation code as above, but this time you should detect that it's an AJAX request (e.g. by using some special HTTP header or a request variable) and instead of saving errors to session variables and redirecting, you should convert them into a JSON form and return them.
3. When the validation AJAX returns, process the response and act accordingly.

Comment: @user1002039: Change the code to work as above, or accept that your site will not work without Javascript. There is no third option.

Comment: Sorry Jon, the the form works just fine without javascript. If javascript is not enabled, the form just submits as a regular form. The solution was provided by Jasper below....

Comment: @user1002039: Jasper suggests exactly the same thing as I do, except that a) he doesn't mention what your code needs to do *after* that `if` and b) he doesn't use PRG. But if you 're happy with that solution it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

If javascript is not enabled, then your jQuery call will not execute anyway.  Your app will be dead.  I'd suggest doing a check for JS on page load and that will let you know whether you can use your jQuery functions or if you have to go with a  post.